# Why CountDownTimer doesn't let lower intervals than 1s?

Tags: android, object, kotlin, timer, countdowntimer

I'm trying to use CountDownTimer object but it doesn't let me to change countDownInternval. If I try to set it to "500", timer works in the same way as if I use "1000". Why is that? It should be twice faster.

```
object : CountDownTimer(30000, 500) {

                override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {

                    TextView.text = (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toString() + ""
                }

                override fun onFinish() {
                   TextView.text = ("done!")
                }
            }.start()
```

Comment: can you add some more info about your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use this code,

```
millisUntilFinished / 1000
```

then the `TextView` can only take integer values, since you are using [integer division](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Intro/expr-int-div.html). It *is* updating roughly twice a second, but it's putting the same integer in there twice in a row, like this:

```
29
29
28
28
27
27
```

...and so on. I recommend you try either this:

```
millisUntilFinished
```

or this:

```
millisUntilFinished / 1000.0f
```

so that you can see each update, and gain a greater appreciation for the practical accuracy of a `CountDownTimer`.